# How to identify the missing JBoss EAP module

Tags: jboss6.x, jboss-eap-6

I have a module that lists as dependencies,

```
--dependencies=javax.servlet.api,javax.security.jacc.api,org.jboss.logging,org.picketbox,org.picketlink.federation,org.picketlink.federation.bindings,org.jboss.as.web
```

but eap complains about a missing class,

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   **javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse** from [Module
>   "com.td.cbaw.oauthlogin:main" from local module loader @16f65612
>   (finder: local module finder @311d617d (roots:
>   /opt/jboss/EAP-6.4.0/modules,/opt/jboss/EAP-6.4.0/modules/system/layers/base))]

The **javax.servlet.api** module contains the class in question

> ```
>  ...
>  81 javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.class
>  82 javax/servlet/http/LocalStrings_es.properties
>  83 javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionContext.class
>  84 javax/servlet/http/NoBodyOutputStream.class
>  85 javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.class   <====
>  86 javax/servlet/http/HttpUtils.class
>  87 javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.class
>  88 javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionActivationListener.class
>  ....
> ```

How does one root cause this kind of problem?

This is the sum total of information I have found on the subject, [Find_the_JBoss_Module_Dependency](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Migration_Guide/Find_the_JBoss_Module_Dependency1.html), essentially useless docs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at logs seems you are missing `jboss-servlet-api_3.0` JBoss module. To fix that, follow below steps:

**Step 1:** Create directory `javax/servlet/api/main`, as `EAP-6.4.0/modules/system/layers/base/javax/servlet/api/main`

**Step 2:** Create `module.xml` inside the directory created with below content:

**EAP-6.4.0/modules/system/layers/base/javax/servlet/api/main/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="javax.servlet.api">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>
</module>
```

**Step 3:** Download `jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2` from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet/jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec and put it inside **EAP-6.4.0/modules/system/layers/base/javax/servlet/api/main** directory and restart the server.

Comment: I should have said that the javax.servlet.api module is installed.

Comment: accepted this answer, because it solves the general case of building a module that satisfies a dependency

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem: ID10T error.  My preprocessor of the cli file was not replacing the actual cli file that was being sent to jboss.  I forgot to force copy the template over the cli.  The template I'm using has ${} variables to be substituted, which I am forced to due with sed, because the jboss-cli parser does not perform variable substution on the "module" command.  So, my hack around a bug in jboss-cli was the root cause.